# How do I push my link text down a bit?

Tags: html, css

So I have a news section in the content area of this website, it displays the avatar of the person who posted, a heading, and then a small description.

The problem is, the headings don't line up with the avatars well, and I think it's creating unnecessary space between my vertically aligned news articles.

This is what it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

What I want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like]

Relevant code:

```css
#news {
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}

#news h1 {
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #828CAA;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;
}

#news a {
 color: #00366C;
 margin-top: 3px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#news p {
 padding-left: 5px;
 display: inline;
}

#news img.avatar {
 margin-top: 5px;
 float: left;
 border: 1px #00366C solid;
}
```

```html
<section id="news">
<h1>News</h1>

<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/noavatar.gif" width="33" height="33">Review update #126,251,754</a><br>
<p>You should know the drill by now.</p>
<br><br><br>
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/bumblebee_man.gif" width="33" height="33">I'm alive.</a><br>
<p>And angry.</p>
<br><br><br>
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/noavatar.gif" width="33" height="33">Well now, what do we have here?</a><br>
<p>I do believe that it's a review update.....</p>
<br><br><br>
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/bumblebee_man.gif" width="33" height="33">I blame society.</a><br>
<p>Games! Games? Games?</p>
<br><br><br>
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/bumblebee_man.gif" width="33" height="33">Fade may have lied.</a><br>
<p>Have I?</p>
<br><br><br>
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/bartavvy.gif" width="33" height="33">THE GAME DROUGHT IS OVER!</a><br>
<p>Click here for lots of exciting new games!</p>
<br><br><br>

</section>
```

Comment: If you dislike to have a top-margin of 5 pixels for the avatar image, why do you command it with the CSS rule to have it in the first place? And please check your question source, the "code snippet" stuff most likely is not useful and should therefore be removed (those two blue buttons).

Comment: Because that margin isn't what's causing the empty space between the different highlights. All it does is create a space between the "News" title bar and the top avatar. Otherwise it would be "stuck" to the bar, which looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#news {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}

#news h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #828CAA;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 5px 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#news a {
    color: #00366C;
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#news p {
    padding-left: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

#news .avatar {
  vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 1px #00366C solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the title text within a span and add padding to the top.

```
<a href=""><img class="avatar" src="images/noavatar.gif" width="33" height="33"><span class="heading-spacer">Review update #126,251,754</span></a><br>
<p>You should know the drill by now.</p>
```

and the css:

```
.heading-spacer {
   display:inline-block;
   padding-top:10px;
}
```

See if something like that works

here's a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrgRNp

Comment: But I want less space between the headings, not more.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrgRNp

Try that, added a div container around each news element, that should allow you to space each news block how you like, use this in conjunction with what I said before and you should be able to do what you want.